# Unexpected behaviour in Internet Explorer 10 and document.cookie

Tags: cookies, internet-explorer-10

I'm struggling with IE 10 and document.cookie, and this behaviour is for me unexpected..

If I use this code in the developer console in IE 10

```
document.cookie="withactualpathanddomain=nb; path=/pathname/; domain=localhost";
document.cookie="withactualpath=nb; path=/pathname/;";
document.cookie="withpathanddomain=nb; path=/; domain=localhost";
document.cookie="withdomain=nb; domain=localhost";
document.cookie="justname=nb;";
```

The browser only sets two cookies: "justname" and "withactualpath".

If I do this in IE 9 developer console (or firebug with firefox), I get all cookies set.

Is this expected behaviour in IE10? I've tried this in production environment (open domain), same results.

In IE 10, I have the setting "Accept all cookies". I can't change the security settings within this network (customer), could the security settings be the issue here? The settings are "Medium high" for Internet, "Medium low" for Internal network..

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, **IE 10 follows the w3 spec verbatum** ( http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2109/rfc2109 ), not allowing "localhost" as a domain.. So the fix is to **ommit "domain" when setting cookies on localhost**. Adjusted testcase (cookie names not altered for consistency with issue):

```
document.cookie="withactualpathanddomain=nb; path=/pathname/;";
document.cookie="withactualpath=nb; path=/pathname/;";
document.cookie="withpathanddomain=nb; path=/;";
document.cookie="withdomain=nb;";
document.cookie="justname=nb;";
```